# Network Detection using Spectral Clustering, are there any good function in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I currently have an adjacency matrix I would like to perform spectral clustering on to determine the community each node belongs to. I have looked around, but there do not look to be implementations in either `igraph` or other packages.

Another issue is determining how many clusters you want. I was wondering if `R` has any packages that might help one find the optimal number of clusters to break an adjacency matrix into? Thanks.

Comment: You say that you do not see it in igraph, but isn't that what `embed_adjacency_matrix ` does?

Comment: Thanks! I just ran the `embed_adjacency_matrix` function. It seems to give positions, but how can I obtain a vector of which group each node was classified to?

Comment: the cluster_leading_eigen() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot advise for R, however, I can suggest [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309153198_NumPy_SciPy_NetworkX_Recipes_for_Data_Science_Spectral_Clustering) example implementation of Spectral Clustering using Python and Networkx (which is comparable to iGraph). It should not be hard to translate this into R.
For an introduction to Spectral Clustering see lectures 28-34 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0_vNfNZ4JM&list=PLLssT5z_DsK9JDLcT8T62VtzwyW9LNepV&index=28) and [this paper](https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-spectral.pdf).